# Bounce Processing and Process Inbound Emails Failure, Error message: Could not connect to MailStore

Tags: civimail, scheduled-job, bounce-processing

We have recently been getting scheduled job failure notices for both Bounce Processing and Process Inbound Emails. This happened out of the blue a week or two ago... it's been fine for a good couple of years. Nothing has changed with the email associated with these jobs. I have changed the password to the email address in case there was an issue there, but it's still not working. I have been in Microsoft settings as well and can't see anything that would have changed. Can anyone help?

We are running CiviCRM version 5.52.2 with Joomla 3.10.11

**Bounce Processing Error Details:**

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method):
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message:
Finished execution of Fetch Bounces with result: Failure, Error message: Could not connect to MailStore for xxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.org@outlook.office365.com
Error message:

An error occured while sending or receiving mail. The IMAP server did not accept the password: -ERR Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

**Process Inbound Emails Error Details:**

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method):
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message:
Finished execution of Process Inbound Emails with result: Failure, Error message: Could not connect to MailStore for xxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.org@outlook.office365.com
Error message:

An error occured while sending or receiving mail. The IMAP server did not accept the username and/or password: A0001 NO LOGIN failed..

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same thing!

It seems like Microsoft is depreceating Basic Authentication (at the end of October 2022)

Here is a walkthrough I received on email from our phone company, fixing this:

5 steps to show how to opt-out of disabling Basic Auth for EWS in Microsoft 365 Admin Center interface.

1. Log in to Microsoft 365 Admin Center and click the green Help and support button in the lower right hand corner of the screen.
2. Search for “Diag: Enable Basic Auth in EXO” in the search field
3. Click “Run Tests”
4. Choose “IMAP” in the “Protocol to Opt Out” drop down and select “Update”.
5. Microsoft will run Diagnose for a short while and display the below view if successful.

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue and our IT support say it is to do with changes Microsoft have made and that they may allow us to process again temporarily but it will stop completely in December so we need to find a permanent fix.  Has anyone found one as yet?

Comment: if they have they haven't seen this ticket :-p - Gillian what is your approach now it is December?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Just thinking out loud, would it be possible to redirect such emails to a less secure email host, that still has Basic Auth. Seems like Gmail has deprecated already. Any tip on a email provider that you know of?